Uncorrect syntax highlight with keyboard schortcut
With keyboard schortcut: Ctrl + /
https://i.sstatic.net/tNnzh4yf.png
And again, when remove comments, syntax highlight look like that
https://i.sstatic.net/e8TJ5WVv.png
I found that after any line modification, such as adding or removing a character, the correct code highlighting is applied.
And same problem i have not only with JS
I tried:

disable all extensions
change vs code theme
clear vs code cache
clear user settings.json
check new updates
reinstall vs code
reboot Windows

I excepting:
normal behaivor like this
(https://i.sstatic.net/oFWDBaA4.png)

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
